# angular-oauth2-oidc - loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin() always returns false and redirecting to this.oAuthService.tryLogin(). in angular15

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, oauth

Hi I am working with Angular15 application. I am facing issues with my code. How to configure “oAuth2” to my application?

**environment.ts:**

```
{
profile:"TEST",
  serverUrl: 'https://myserverurl.com/',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  clientId: ‘myClient ID',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200//logout',
  oauthDomainURL: myoAuthDomain.com',
  issuer: ‘myIssuer.com',    
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  scope: 'openid profile',  
  clearHashAfterLogin: false,
  loginUrl: "mylogin.com",
  requireHttps: true,
  oidc: true,
  showDebugInformation: true,
}
```

**Appconstants.ts**

```
import { environment } from "../../../src/environments/environment";
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

export class CONSTANTS {
 }
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    issuer: environment.issuer,
    redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
    clientId: environment.clientId,
    responseType: environment.responseType,
    scope: environment.scope,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.postLogoutRedirectUri,
    requireHttps: true,
    oidc: true,
    showDebugInformation: true,
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { authConfig } from './util/Appconstants';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwksValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private router: Router,public oAuthService: OAuthService,private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.login();
  }
async login() {
this.oAuthService.configure(authConfig);
    this.oAuthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler(); 
    this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin().then(res => {
      if (res) {
        if (this.oAuthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
          const userClaim: any = this.oAuthService.getIdentityClaims();
          if (userClaim) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', this.oAuthService.getAccessToken()); 
          }
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      }
      this.oAuthService.tryLogin()
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        })
        .then(() => {
          if (!this.oAuthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
            this.oAuthService.initImplicitFlow();
          }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

In above code it is always going to `this.oAuthService.tryLogin()`. The method `this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin()` **res** value is always returns “**false**”. Verified the “**authConfig**” details with client. There is no issue with the Url, Uri and ClientId. But I am unable to set the token in session.

I am unable to get true value with `this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin()`. Am i missing any configuration parameters in **authConfig**?

Comment: One possible issue is that your `if` has no `else`. So, `this.oAuthService.tryLogin` will always be called no matter what.